# Use UIPageViewController together with UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

My application is a page based application using UIPageViewController. Now I would like to able to move subviews vertically on my pages. After implementing a UIPanGestureRecognizer I was able to move the subviews but now my horizontal swiping to move through the pages does not work...

How can I combine those two gestures?
This is my panGestureRecognizer:

ContentViewController.swift

```
var panSwipe = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handlePanSwipe:"))

view.addGestureRecognizer(panSwipe)

...

func handlePanSwipe(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    var translation = sender.translationInView(self.view)

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        startLocation = sender.locationInView(self.view)
    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed) {
        self.settingsView.frame.origin.y = self.newSettingsFrameOrigin!.y + translation.y
    } else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
        self.newSettingsFrameOrigin = self.settingsView.frame.origin
}
```

I want to be able to move the dark green subview up and down:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want the UIPanGesture to for example show a "menu/more info bar" when user swipes up. Then if they swipe down hide the "menu/more info bar? Or do you want the user to be able to use the UIPanGesture to slide up/down to show a diff VC?

Comment: I want to show a "menu/more info bar" exactly! The dark green area in my screen is supposed to be a small menu that comes out when swiping up.

Comment: Did you figure out how to use these two together?

Comment: Eventually I gave up and changed my apps design...